# Eclipse Moonrise console background

Tags: eclipse, themes

I am not sure if I am the only one with this problem but I can't seem to fix it. I am using Eclipse Kepler and Moonrise Standalone (dark) theme. 
The problem is with the console window which has dark font on dark background. I've tried to change the colors under *Preferences -> Run/Debug -> Console* to no avail.

[image]

The funny thing is that the console has white background upon startup but changes to black as soon as I click on it. I haven't found any css file for Moonrise theme.

Is this possible to fix or am I stuck with the default white theme?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The issue has been (finally!) resolved. The console color scheme can be changed under *Preferences->C/C++->Build->Console*, if you're using CDT of course.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Preference -> Run/Debug -> Console  then change "standard out text color".